# Unable to read an Excel file instead showing the else Toast "Please select an excel file" in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, apache-poi, filepath

I am new to Android and java. This is a quiz admin app from Tcodestudio on youtube. I am not able to read the excel file while the video from which I tried this code has done it with the same code.
Also I have already used poi jar file and not getting any error it's just showing the else message "Please select an excel file" instead of reading the excel file

It is in OnActivity result code is in the last para.

```
        excel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(QuestionsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    selectfile();
                }else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(QuestionsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},101);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == 101){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                selectfile();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Grant Permissions!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void selectfile() {
       //  select the file from the file storage
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), 102);


    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 102) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
                if (filepath.endsWith(".xlsx")||filepath.endsWith(".xls")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yesssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    readFile(data.getData());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please add an Excel File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is in an admin app for another app that is a quiz app. No Error is showing just not able to read excel file. Checked with different excel files but the problem is same. Please HELP!

Comment: You posted way too much code. Most code is irrelevant for your problem. Nobody will dig through that all in order to find the problematic code.

Comment: @blackapps Alright I am new so didn't new how to post questions here and thanks for telling that I edited the code and now it is only showing the problem!

Comment: OK. Much better. But you could remove that permission code too. As you could just say that you requested and got permission at runtime.

Comment: `String filepath = data.getData().getPath();` That is no filepath at all. But indeed it can contain the filename. But not always! You are further doing nothing with it but why not Toast it? Or Log.d() it?Then you see the value you got and you would know that it is not a file path. Add a separate Toast where you toast data.getData().toString() to see the content scheme you got. Also Lod.d() that variable.

Comment: `it's just showing the else message "Please select an excel file"` But that is your own error message. (And a bad error messge, sorry). Instead you should tell what went wrong. Well you expected a certain extension. So tell what you got instead.

Comment: Please let the user select an exel file and then tell us the value of data.getData().getPath() and data.getData().toString().

Comment: `I am not able to read the excel file` ??? Well you are not trying to read it. You reject the obtained uri before you try to read. So the real problem is different.